# What's the difference between 行为 and 现象?

Tags: difference

> 从（软件运行的）**现象**上来看，这个问题不影响软件的正常使用。

According to the dictionary, 现象 is phenomenon. I think it should be behavior, but behavior means 行为.

Comment: 我觉得这里的现象是直观感受 intuitive feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides meaning 'a phenomenon', a more literal understanding of 現象 is 'the appearance of things'*. By character, 現 means 'to appear; to reveal'; 象 means 'resemblance; appearance'. May think of that as 表現之象.

This sentence may mean something like this:

'From the way the software runs, it *appears* that this problem does not affect the normal functioning of the software.'

In this context, 現象 is akin to 表徵, 表面.

行為 as a substitute of 現象 is grammatically plausible. But their meanings differ slightly; while 行為 is a neutral phrasing, 現象 seems to be a more conservative way of assessing the effect of the problem on the software - the speaker's judgement is only based on how the software *appears* to them, not necessarily how the software actually *is* under the influence of the problem.

* Reference: 譯典通英漢雙向字典

Comment: IMHO, very broadly, 現象 applies more towards non-human, inanimate objects' appearances, phenomena, and 行為 for the "impression" one gets from human behavior and actions.

Comment: That is indeed true.

Comment: Of course one can treat the software as if it were animate; that works as well.

Comment: Quote:- "...one can treat the software as if it were animate...." That's interesting because in a cartoon where human figures / characters are depicted, (these human characters are clearly not "alive"), one would actually describe their behavior as 行為?

Comment: Precisely. In this context, I see the software as almost AI-like, if 行為 is used.